# i cant do the min of a sum of values order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

im working in sql server 2005
i dont know how to get the min value of the column which this returns. i have tried different ways but dont get the solution. Thanks

```
select sum(c.duration) 
from song c , disc d, have e
where d.cod = e.cod AND e.can = c.cod 
group by d.name
```

tables:

```
song          have       disc
--------    -------   -----------
cod(int)     can(int)  cod
title        cod       name
duration               date
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Hint... add d.name to the select, wrap it in a CTE, then select the min from the cte or use a sub-query

Comment: i have tried this but dont return nothing, i dont know how to continue :        select d.name, min(c.duration) 
from song c , disc d, have e
where d.cod = e.cod AND e.can = c.cod 
  AND c.duration = (select sum(duration) from song) 
group by d.name

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the minimum from the summations, then a simple ordering will do.

```
select top 1 sum(c.duration) as SumDuration
    from song c
    inner join have e on e.can = c.cod
    inner join disc d on d.cod = e.cod
    group by d.name
    order by SumDuration asc
```

If you want to output all the summed records that have that minimum, then using a CTE should work

```
; with
    CTE as (
        select d.name, sum(c.duration) as SumDuration
            from song c
            inner join have e on e.can = c.cod
            inner join disc d on d.cod = e.cod
            group by d.name
    )
select name, SumDuration
    from CTE
    where SumDuration = (
        select min(SumDuration)
            from CTE
    )
```

Comment: but if you have more than one with that minimun value?

Comment: @DavidArguedas I've updated the answer to allow for this result.

Comment: it looks nice. Just give me an error: Msg. 170, level 15, state 1, Line 1
Line 1:  Incorrect syntax  near ';'.              sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: @DavidArguedas Try removing the semicolon